# Pandas - Creating calculated column for > or < a number

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns

I am new to `python`/`pandas` and trying to create a calculated column on a data frame.

I wanted to add a column that would print `“PASS”` or `“FAIL”` based on whether the number in the adjacent column was `>=` or `<` than `10`.

(I am using jupyter notebooks with pandas installed. I have not used `numpy` before but can learn if necessary)

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempts? Please provide a [mcve] with sample input and expected output so that we can understand how to best help you

Comment: DataFrames are not spreadsheets and do not dynamically update.  The way you've described the problem, it sounds like you want the PASS/FAIL to change if the order of the columns changes.  This wouldn't happen.  The PASS/FAIL would be calculated once and dropped into the column.  If you needed it updated, you'd need to calculate it again.  Just making sure that is clear.

Comment: What do you mean by adhacent column? It's better to add some data to the question